# ruby "on error resume next" function

Tags: ruby

Is there a way of doing the old "on error resume next" routine in ruby?

I've got array of value filled in dynamically from elsewhere (read from MQTT topics to be precise) then I want to do a bunch of numeric calculations on them and publish the results.  The values SHOULD be numeric but are possibly missing or non-numeric.

At the moment my code looks something like

```
values=[]


//values get loaded here 

begin
  Publish('topic1',value[0]*10+value[1])
rescue TypeError,NoMethodError,ZeroDivisionError
end

begin
  Publish('topic2',value[3]/value[4])
rescue TypeError,NoMethodError,ZeroDivisionError
end

//etc etc
```

If the calculation fails for any reason the program should just skip that step and go on.

It works but surely theres a better way than all those identical begin..rescue blocks? Ruby is about "DRY" after all..

Is there a way of re-writing the above so that a single begin..rescue construct is used while still allowing all calculations to be attempted?

**UPDATED**

How safe to do something like

```
def safe_Publish(topic,value)
  return if value.nil?
  Publish(topic,value)
end
```

and call with
    safe_Publish('topic2',(value[3]/value[4] rescue nil))

The main problem is that the above catches ALL exceptions not just the ones I'm expecting which makes me a little nervous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `on error resume next` coding style is really dangerous - as it makes finding new bugs you accidentally introduce to your program very hard to find. Instead, I would just write a different version of publish that doesn't throw those exceptions:

```
def try_publish(topic_name)
  begin
    Publish('topic1',yield)
  rescue TypeError,NoMethodError,ZeroDivisionError
    # are you sure you don't want to do anything here? Even logging the errors
    # somewhere could be useful.
  end
end
```

You can then call this with:

```
try_publish('topic1') { value[0]*10+value[1] }
```

If TypeError,NoMethodError or ZeroDivisionError are thrown by the expression, they will be caught and ignored.

Now your original method won't require any rescues.

---

If you really wanted an `on error resume next`, you could possibly do it by monkey patching the `raise` method in Kernel, but that would be a horrible idea.

Comment: :Can you clarify?  If you meant to write "Publish(topic_name,value)" and be called with "try_publish('topic1',value[0]*10+value[1])  then surely the numeric exception gets thrown before the method is called?

Comment: Sorry, my original answer wasn't useful at all. I've fixed it now by using a block to pass the computation that might fail in. As the block is executed in the inner begin/rescue section, the exceptions will be caught.

Comment: nanothief- that looks lots better.  Being a perl guy who's new to ruby I'm still getting my head around code blocks and yield()

Comment: Apologies to the others who essentially suggested the same solution: your input is just as valued but I had to choose only one "accepted answer".  I've learnt the power of code blocks, thanks folks!

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to wrap a bunch of quick operations into a loop with each one being protected by a begin/rescue:

```
values = [1,2,3,0,4]
ops = [ ->{values[0]/values[1]}, ->{values[2]/values[3]} ]

ops.each do |op|
  begin
    puts "answer is #{op.call}"
  rescue ZeroDivisionError
    puts "cannot divide by zero"
  end
end
```

I prefer the `safe_publish` method, however, as you can unit test that and it encapsulates the logic of making safe calls and handling errors in a single place:

```
def safe_publish(topic, &block)
  begin
    value = block.call
    publish(topic, value)
  rescue
    # handle the error
  end
end
```

and then you can call this with code like:

```
safe_publish 'topic0' do
  value[0]*10+value[1]
end
```

Comment: That will work OK if you want the same calculation for each value, not for different calculations

Comment: `def` is an implicit begin, so you can remove the `begin` from your version of `safe_publish`.

Comment: Am I right that ->{} is similar to lambda{} ie an anonymous function? Still trying to get to grips with code-blocks, lambdas and Procs, if anyone has a good guide I'd be most grateful

Answer (score 0):

If you think a bit more carefully about what you are doing, and *why* you want `on error resume next`, I think you will see that you don't really need to suppress *all* exceptions. As the other posters pointed out, that would make it hard to find and fix bugs.

Your problem is that you have a bunch of numbers scraped from the Internet, and want to run some calculations on them, but some may be invalid or missing. For invalid/missing numbers, you want to skip over any calculations which would use those numbers.

A few possible solutions:

1. Pre-filter your data and remove anything which is not a valid number.
2. Put each calculation you want to do into a method of its own. Put a `rescue Exception` on the method definition.
3. Define "safe" wrappers for the numeric classes which don't raise exceptions on divide by zero, etc. Use these wrappers for your calculations.

The "wrappers" might look something like this (don't expect complete, tested code; this is just to give you the idea):

```
# This is not designed for "mixed" arithmetic between SafeNumerics and ordinary Numerics,
# but if you want to do mixed arithmetic, that can also be achieved
# more checks will be needed, and it will also need a "coerce" method
class SafeNumeric
  attr_reader :__numeric__
  def initialize(numeric)
    @__numeric__ = numeric.is_a?(String) ? numeric.to_f : numeric
  end

  def zero?
    @__numeric__.zero?
  end
  def /(other)
    if other.zero? || @__numeric__.nil? || other.__numeric__.nil?
      SafeNumeric.new(nil) # could use a constant for this to reduce allocations
    else
      SafeNumeric.new(@__numeric__ / other.__numeric__)
    end
  end

  def to_s; @__numeric__.to_s; end
  def inspect; @__numeric__.inspect; end

  # methods are also needed for +, -, *
end
```

Then use it like:

```
numbers = scraped_from_net.map { |n| SafeNumeric.new(n) }
# now you can do arithmetic on "numbers" at will
```

Comment: 2. is basically what I am doing now without the method call. Can you post sample code for 3.?

Comment: Being an old perl guy but a ruby n00b I'm struggling to understand most of this- although I'm sure its great code! Operator overloading always did mess with my head. Is "@__numeric__" is some kind of reference to the parent class/function?

Comment: No, it's just a variable which holds a number, and the name is completely arbitrary. Remember that in Ruby, "operators" like +, -, etc. are just method calls. All I am doing is defining these operators on a custom class, which holds a number and does some checks before trying to perform any operations on the number.